# Can I ask Factory Girl if a given factory exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a series of models for which I've defined factories. I also have an API-based model which subclasses `ActiveResource::Base`, which I (apparently) cannot build from a factory--I get an exception when [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) calls `FooAPI.new`.

I've instead defined a `Foo` class in `test/lib`. What I'd like to do in my test is see if a factory exists for a given symbol (e.g. `:foo`, `:bar`, etc.), then fall back to attempting to directly construct an object of the appropriate class, using `String#classify.constantize`. Here's my current clunky implementation:

```
  objects[name] = begin
    klass = name.to_s.classify.constantize
    klass.new
  rescue
    Factory.build name
  end
```

I'd prefer something like this:

```
Factory.exists?(name) ? Factory.build(name) : name.to_s.classify.constantize.new
```

That way, I'd get an appropriate exception on a failure to construct an object.

**Update:** Thanks to [fd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13956/fd), I found a way to do this without exception handling!

```
  objects[name] = if Factory.factories.include?(name)
    Factory.build name
  else
    klass = name.to_s.classify.constantize
    klass.new
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From peeping at the latest:

```
FactoryGirl.find(name)
```

..should give you the factory.

This replaces the now deprecated:

```
FactoryGirl.factory_by_name(name)
```

Comment: Hrm, that doesn't seem to work for me. I get a `NameError: uninitialized constant FooTest::FactoryGirl` with `FactoryGirl.find :foo` and a `NoMethodError: undefined method `find' for Factory:Class` with `Factory.find :foo`. I wonder if it has to do with the Rails integration?

Comment: I don't think it exists in 1.3, all I see is `Factory.factories[name]` as an equivalent. Seems a little raw, probably removed in the later versions.

Answer (score 15):

What works in the later versions of FactoryBot is

```
FactoryBot.factories.registered?(name)
```

Comment: Now `FactoryBot.factories.registered?(:name)`

Answer (score 1):

Having thought about it for an hour, I realised that this:

```
objects[name] = Factory.exists?(name) ? Factory.build(name) : name.to_s.classify.constantize.new
```

is really not different from this:

```
objects[name] = begin
  Factory.build name
rescue ArgumentError => e
  raise unless e.message == "No such factory: #{name}"
  name.to_s.classify.constantize.new
end
```

So I think I'll just go with that. :)

Comment: Only downside is if they change the error message. However, if you're not on the later versions, then the alternatives to this approach (in my answer) are also brittle (since the latest version seems to deprecate/remove them.)